# Ionic Popover Component CSS

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using the popover from ioninic 4. Here's the main code:

```
async presentPopover(ev: any) {
    this.popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: MenuComponent,
      event: ev,
      translucent: true,
      backdropDismiss: true,
      keyboardClose: true,
      animated: false,
      cssClass: 'menu-popover',
      componentProps: {
        popover: this.popover
      }
    });
    return await this.popover.present().then(() => this.removeOverflow());
  }
```

MenuComponent.html:

```
<ion-content id="popover">
  <ion-row class="button-menu" *ngFor="let option of options">
    <ion-col class="ion-text-center" (click)="getFunction( option)">
      <img [src]="option.image" class="menu-icon" *ngIf="option.image">
      <span class="bold">
        <i class="fas" [ngClass]="option.icon" *ngIf="option.icon"></i>
        {{option.text | translate}}
        <span *ngIf="option.index">{{option.index}}</span>
      </span>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
  <ion-row class="button-menu footer">
    <ion-col class="justify-center">
      {{ 'VERSION' | translate }}:&nbsp;{{version}}
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</ion-content>
```

And when the popover is rendered, some new components are generated. My issue is that I want to change the width of a popover-content. But it won't work:

[image: this popover component]

How can I change the CSS of this popover-content?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, I added this code in variables.scss

```
ion-popover {
    --width: 320px;
}
```